# Redmine : save data fail the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save, redmine

I'm trying to save a new Issue_relation in the database. This is my model

```
class BetterGanttChart < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.create_new_relation(issue_from, issue_to, relation_type)
    issue_relation = IssueRelation.new(relation_type: relation_type)
    issue_relation.issue_from = issue_from
    issue_relation.issue_to = issue_to
    issue_relation.save
end
end
```

I execute it from rails console. The first time it returns me `false`, which means that `issue_relation` is not saved. And when I execute it a second time it works.

*Can someone help me to make it work on the first time ?*

Comment: if `issue_relation.save` returns false then it means that the record is invalid. You can change code to use `save!` - in this case you will see what attribute is invalid

Comment: I don't understand why, but when I did what you asked, it worked on the first time because of the "!". Without it I need to do the request twice, and with it I need only one time. Thanks gotva